# Jake exec not displaying exec output on windows

Tags: javascript, exec, stdout, tsc, jake

I have a simple command which im running in Jake, and it keeps failing however it doesn't tell me what the failure reason is.

The command is the typescript compiler so the command looks like so:

`tsc app.ts`

Then the actual jake command looks like:

`jake.exec("tsc app.ts", {interactive: true}, callback)`

However I just get a generic Jake error. I have tried using stdout/stderr and printStdout/printStdout. Still no output from the exec, I know what the issue is, however I would be expecting it to output something like:

`<some dir>/repository.ts(8,26): error TS1005: '{' expected.`

As if I run it manually in the command line I see this output. So is there some magic I am missing in Jake to make this output as part of the exec call?

== EDIT ==

Just to avoid confusion I am using version 0.5.16 of Jake.

Comment: Did you make sure to mark the task as async? I spend a good day or two tracking down the fact that I forgot to specify that on the task and the task ended before the compile failed.